# Laravel allow only one session per user

Tags: php, laravel, session, web, laravel-5.8

I am trying to allow only one session per user. So if someone tries to log in when he already logged in his user account, the user is not allowed to login. The second user can login only when the first user logged out from his account. help please

Comment: add a row in user table for user login or logout status and check it when user wants to Auth